# How to create a new static ip address along with the dynamic one in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ip-address, static-ip, dynamic-ip

The **dynamic IP-address** causes some problems since it changes frequently . I have to configure my application every time I run it. I have decided to use a static IP-addressing but soon I realized that I will be targeted by hackers if its always static.

Can I add a **new static IP-address** for this chat application along with the old **dynamic IP-address.**

If so how it is done?

Comment: You can, but that static IP will be the target for hackers then... Also, routing becomes painful.

Comment: Where do you want the static address? LAN or WAN? If LAN you just set it in your router, that way you don't mess up DHCP. WAN, you'd need to buy one from your ISP.

Comment: @Tetsujin I am running ubuntu through virtual box & host is windows and I m using internet through intel wifi chip on my laptop.

Comment: That still doesn't tell me where you want the static IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How it's done:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/585468/how-do-i-add-an-additional-ip-address-to-an-interface-in-ubuntu-14

although, @davidgo's comment is right.  Routing is probably going to be an issue for you.  Practically, the easy way to handle routing is to have your ISP provide you with a statically-assigned IP address (assigned by them).  That is going to be your major hurdle, and so should be your first step.  That can be as easy as asking them for it, or convincing them by paying them monthly.  Details vary based on what ISP you use.  Paying for it is a quite common requirement.

The alternative would typically involve a combination of DDNS and then routing traffic to that address, possibly by using a tunnel such as a VPN.

Comment: I know this answer is rather broad, and maybe you were hoping for something more specific.  However, this answer is probably accurate, even if not what you were hoping for.  So use this answer as a plan.  There will probably be some steps that will require some additional planning and/or more questions to be asked.  You'll probably be best off asking those questions separately, as specific questions.  This task will probably take some number of hours to get set up, fully working well.  To implement security, learn the secure options for each individual step along the way.